# Why doesn't my code recognize the element added to the array?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, java.util.scanner

So I am making a program that can add, edit and delete records from a 2d array.

What I have done to add an array is to collect input from the user by Scanner, and then turn it into an array, and then use java.utils.Arrays to make a copy of the array and then overwrite the original array

This is done through the code below:

```
static String[][] AssManager = {
            {"Natasha Binti Iman Raman", "natasha.raman@taylors.edu.my", "0123659546", "nat123"},
            {"Navid Ali Khan", "navidali.khan@taylors.edu.my", "0114665985", "navid123"},
            {"Tan Zheng Shen", "zhengshen.tan@taylors.edu.my", "0165846598", "dex123"},
            {"Teh Wei Shen", "weishen.tay@taylors.edu.my", "0161254925", "wei123"}
        };


Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] role = {
                        "",
                        "",
                        "",
                        ""
                   };

                    System.out.println("Please enter the name.");
                    role[0] = inp.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the email");
                    role[1] = inp.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the phone number");
                    role [2] = inp.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Please enter the password");
                    role[3] = inp.nextLine();

                    AssManager = Arrays.copyOf(AssManager, AssManager.length + 1);

                    AssManager[AssManager.length-1] = role;
```

As for editing and deleting, I pinpoint the the array to be deleted using by collecting input from the user, and then checking whether the particular row actually exists. If it doesn't exist, then it will print out a statement. If it exists, it will then allow me to modify or delete the particular row.

The difficulty that I am facing is that while checking for the rows, it only recognizes the dummy data that already exists, but not the newly made rows.

This is the code used to check whether the row exists::

```
boolean existing = false;
for (int i = 0 ; i < AssManager.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (name.equals(AssManager[i][0])){

                        existing = true;

                    }
```

Any row that I made through the program is ignored and I am given the statement that the specific row does not exist.

I have tried to make more copies of the same array while using java.util.Arrays but to no avail. I have also tried searching up my problem elsewhere but I cannot find any solutions that may help me.

I appreciate any sort of advice.

Comment: `i < AssManager.length - 1;` <- If your array has a length of 5 you iterate from 0 to 3, missing the last index 4. Either remove the `- 1` or change `<` to `<=`

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I had the exact same problem with another section of my code and fixed it without help, and yet I didn't manage to see through my careless mistake in this part of the code... How embarassing haha

Answer (score 0):

Is there a specific reason you're using a two dimensional array? It makes things unnecessarily complex.
I'd suggest you use an ArrayList. This makes adding, removing and even replacing a lot easier.
Additionally, you should create some kind of entity for the name, email, phone number and password information.

Comment: I wasn't entirely sure if I would be able to do the same of what I had already done in an ArrayList as compared to a 2d array. Also, I am in the process of learning Java and my lecturer had not taught us about entities and so I had not even thought of using entities as a way to store information. That being said, I have found the error in my code, thanks to OH GOD SPIDERS. I appreciate your insight and advice.